# EF Core Inheritance Queries When Using a Single Table

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

Here's a .NET EF Core simplified scenario that I have been working on:

```
abstract class Colour
class Blue : Colour
class Green : Colour

class MyClass {
  public List<Colour> Colours { get; set; }
}
```

I have set the database up so that all colours are in one table:

public DbSet Blues { get; set; }
public DbSet Greens { get; set; }

```
builder.Entity<Colour>()
.ToTable("Colours")
.HasDiscriminator<int>("ColourType")
.HasValue<Blue>((int)ColourType.Blue)
.HasValue<Green>((int)ColourType.Green);
```

When I am querying using LINQ, I can do the following:

```
List<Colours> MyList = MyClass.Colours;
```

The above query returns a list of all colour types.

My question is this. How do I do a direct LINQ query to retrieve all colours? It is not possible to do: DbContext.Colours. The options that I have are DbContext.Blues and DbContext.Greens. Another scenario is when I want to retrieve a Colour but I do not know what type it is.

Comment: U can't have this with EF Core. Each table has it own mapping. You can use the concat function to have something like this. var query = (from x in db.Table1 select new {A = x.A, B = x.B}) .Concat( from y in db.Table2 select new {A = y.A, B = y.B} );

Comment: Thanks @DA. Not ideal when there are quite a few classes but it does work. I was hoping there's a way to define some sort of custom table or query in the DbContext class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I do a direct LINQ query to retrieve all colours?

You've already configured Color as an entity in your DbContext, so you can siply write

```
var colors = db.Set<Color>().ToList();
```

Or add a DbSet for it:

```
  public DbSet<Blue> Blues { get; set; }
  public DbSet<Green> Greens { get; set; }
  public DbSet<Color> Colors{ get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you David!! I didn't know you can do this. It's exactly what I wanted.